# How to pin TabLaout at top of ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have an Layout with a Custom TabLayout and other things in a ScrollView I want to pin the tab at top , my TabLayout isn't the support design tab , is there any way to do that?!

here is how my layout looks like
[image]